# Magento Product Flat Data Reindex causes error

Tags: magento, indexing

I cannot reindex the Product flat data because I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fpshop/#sql-6101_1484e`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CA)
```

Any ideas where to look to fix?

Comment: try with shell reindex
http://magento-rohan.blogspot.in/2012/10/magento-reindex-via-ssh.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database and check all the rows in table `catalog_product_entity` or `catalog_product_flat_1`, particularly the values in column `entity_id`.

Most likely some rows are missing the required values, which means that either someone has messed with the db, or you are using a module, which is messing up the db. Either you will need to delete those broken rows, or fill them with values they are missing.

**fix proposal:**

In order to fix this, try to run a query below to locate the broken rows :

```
SELECT a.entity_id FROM catalog_product_flat_1 AS a LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id WHERE ISNULL(b.entity_id);
```

And then delete those rows you got by doing

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_flat_1 where entity_id = '123456789';
```

where `123456789` is the id of the broken row.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling Flat_catalog_category and Flat_catlaog_product and then truncating the catalog_product_flat tables.Be sure to disable foreign key constraints checks by doing SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; before truncating. Once doing that you should be able to manually reindex via ssh . A well documented solution for this issue is here : http://binarythoughts21.blogspot.in/2013/12/reindexing-problems-in-magento.html